# How to move a value from span into input?

Tags: jquery, html, input

I've got a script from http://jsfiddle.net/nobuts/89NtM/ and wondering if I can make a total number of all inputs into a `<input>` instead of `<span>`

I've tried `<input type="text" id="sum" />` but it's not working for some reasons.
By the way, I'm not a jquery guy. So could you guys please suggest me a solution.

Here is a script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
    //handler to trigger sum event
    $(".txt").each(function() {

        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSum();
        });
    });

});

function calculateSum() {

    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".txt").each(function() { 
        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        } 
    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table width="300px" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;background-color:#E8DCFF">
        <tr>
            <td width="40px">1</td>
            <td>Butter</td>
            <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="cost"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Cheese</td>
            <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="cost"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Eggs</td>
            <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="cost"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Milk</td>
            <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="cost"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Bread</td>
            <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="cost"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>Soap</td>
            <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="cost"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="summation">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="right">Sum :</td>
            <td align="center"><span id="sum">0</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<span id="sum">0</span>
```

to

```
<input id="sum" value="0" />
```

and change

```
$("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
```

to

```
$("#sum").val(sum.toFixed(2));
```